# Input type="image" not loading in IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am using a submit button in a WordPress site. This is my  HTML for the button:

```
<input class="greenbut" onclick="set_srch();" type="image" alt="Search" value="Search"/>
```

And in `style.css` I have:

```
.search_box .greenbut
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: DroidSansRegular;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 31px;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    background-image: none;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 0px;
    background-size: auto;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(137, 206, 71);
}
```

In other browsers it’s okay, but this is how it looks in IE:

[image: Image of broken button]

In Chrome & Firefox it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of search button]

How can I fix it for IE?

Comment: Where is the image src?

Comment: i got it to fix , really not getting why the developer used it

Comment: he used bg  color , text for search  and no image that  causes problem in ie how to fix it ?

Comment: @putvande windows 7 default  .

Comment: Are we to infer that you have no control over the markup?

Comment: What is windows 7 default? IE9?

Comment: @aaronburrows i wil get access to code as i let them know how to fix it , its developed by someone else

Comment: The real solution here is to have a `src` attribute added to the input element. A better solution is to change the input type to submit, or button, depending on the usage, and style it visually with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `type="image"` is to act as a server side image map with the URL of the image specified by a `src` attribute. You don't have one of those, all your styling is done with CSS and you are depending on browsers to handle a missing image and its alternative (`alt`) content in a consistent way. Since IE shows an icon indicating the image is missing in addition to the alt text, this won't work.

Use a real submit button instead:

```
<input class="greenbut" type="submit" value="Search">
```

You might have to adjust the CSS to compensate for the different default borders / margin / padding /etc.

Comment: yes got it to fix , dont know who did i ,how can i mnake i tto use this css instead of depending in image

Comment: You do what I said. You use a submit button and not an image map.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Can you explain why OP can't use `input type="image"`?

Comment: I don't see any image src in your css.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add this `<input type="hidden" alt="Search"  value="Search" />` and remove `alt="Search"`  from your code

Comment: What? That has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: IE works really weird where beside "input type=image and value" you put something else, thats why i wrote this.